# Creating multiple PV and PVC in same kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to create multiple PV and PVC(for each one of the PV) in a single namespace and it is not allowing me to do so. Is this an expected behavior? i am using NFS.

```
NAME                          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                                 STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs-office-tools-service-pv   70Gi       RWX            Retain           Bound       office-tools-service-ns/nfs-office-tools-service-pv   manual                   4d
nfs-perfqa-jenkins-pv         20Gi       RWX            Retain           Available                                                         manual                   8m
nfs-perfqa-pv                 2Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound       perfqa/nfs-perfqa-pvc         

                    manual                   17d
```

When i create a new PVC for the newly created PV, it is giving error as below:
[image]

Below are the yaml for PV and PVC:

PV.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-perfqa-jenkins-pv
  namespace: perfqa
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/nfs_share/docker/test/jenkins"
```

PVC.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-perfqa-jenkins-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cluster has `ResourceQuota` or `LimitRange` with `requests.storage` set to 2Gi. So you cannot create PVC with 20Gi.

Comment: as checked there is no quota set on this namespace.

Comment: it was limitrange that was set on the ns for the pvc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that persistent volume is defined at cluster level. it is not defined at namespace level.

correct pv definition as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-perfqa-jenkins-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/nfs_share/docker/test/jenkins"
```

There is no issue with pv. it is created and is available

```
nfs-perfqa-jenkins-pv         20Gi       RWX            Retain           Available
```

also check for resourceQuota in default namespace. You might have set max storage limit to 2GB